# Display multiple fields of the same solr tag in Blacklight

Tags: solr, blacklight

I have a solr index with nested fields in the form of

```
{ record: [
    { tag1: foo, tag2: bar }
  ]
}
```

The solr configuration cannot be changed, unfortunately.

In Blacklight, I want to display `foo` and `bar` separately under different fields, like so:

```
Tag1: foo
Tag2: bar
```

I was thinking I could just use config.add_index_field with a helper method to achieve this:

```
catalog_controller.rb
config.add_index_field 'record', label: 'Tag1', helper_method: :get_tag1
config.add_index_field 'record', label: 'Tag2', helper_method: :get_tag2
```

```
application_helper.rb
  def get_tag1(options={})
    options[:value][0]['tag1']
  end
  def get_tag2(options={})
    options[:value][0]['tag2']
  end
```

However, when doing so I get the error `A index_field with the key record already exists.`

Apparently, I can only add one index field per solr field at a time. How can I turn one such field into multiple fields in Blacklight?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. I simply need to add the field variable to point to the same tag, that way I can change the original variable.

```
catalog_controller.rb
config.add_index_field 'record1', label: 'Tag1', field: 'record', helper_method: :get_tag1
config.add_index_field 'record2', label: 'Tag2', field: 'record', helper_method: :get_tag2
```